# How to remove the underline and the number after the underline in a column？

Tags: linux

in order to match another file, I need to remove all the underline and the numbers after the underline in the first column.

**I have used the sed tool,I did delete the underline and string after the underline strings in the first column, but I deleted all the other columns that follow,I want to keep the other columns（Each column is separated by tab）**. I am a newcomer just getting started. Hope someone can tell me how to do it,thank you.

The text file that needs to be processed is as follows：（test.txt）

```
ENST00000515896.1   0.177145    0.356609
ENST00000425026.1_1 0.024620    0.049561
ENST00000286448.11_1_PAR_Y  8.465151    17.041147
ENST00000479687.6_1_PAR_Y   0.002051    0.004128
```

Attempt with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/_.\+//g' test.txt
```

expected results:

```
ENST00000515896.1   0.177145    0.356609
ENST00000425026.1       0.024620    0.049561
ENST00000286448.11  8.465151    17.041147
ENST00000479687.6   0.002051    0.004128
```

actual results:

```
ENST00000515896.1   0.177145    0.356609
ENST00000425026.1
ENST00000286448.11
ENST00000479687.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish trimming `'_'` and the remainder of what follows up to the next space, with a simple `sed` substitution, e.g.

```
$ sed 's/_[^ \t]*//' test.txt
ENST00000515896.1 0.177145 0.356609
ENST00000425026.1 0.024620 0.049561
ENST00000286448.11 8.465151 17.041147
ENST00000479687.6 0.002051 0.004128
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you, I successfully solved the problem with this command.I understand the meaning of it, I still have a problem in the shell, can the single quotes be escaped? Don't need change to double quotes?

Comment: If you are having to escape the single quotes -- you are doing something strange or wrong. You can use double-quotes instead of single-quotes -- up to you. You are using `sed 's/find/replace/'` where `find` is `'_'` and any number of characters NOT `space` or `tab` within the character class, e.g. `[^ \t]`. (the `'*'` following means zero-or-more occurrences) Your `replace` is nothing (empty), so it finds everything from `'_'` up to the next whitespace and deletes it (replaces it with nothing). Let me know if that isn't clear.

Comment: I understand what you mean, if it include single quotes or tabs within the characters I need to replace, need to escape. Please forgive me a novice concept is still quite confusing.

Comment: Well. You are looking at it wrong. The only difference between `'s/find/replace/'` and `"s/find/replace/"` is that normal shell *variable-expansion* could take place within the double-quoted version. The only place escaping a quote comes into play is if you are trying to store the command within a string that will also be quoted (bad idea). For normal use, there should be no issue relating to escaping quotes, unless they appear within `find` or `replace` itself. Then it is simply better to use a character class, e.g. `[']` to ensure the quote is made as part of the pattern for `find/replace`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I probably understand. I have seen someone say that if `find` and `replace` contain single quotes, there is no way to escape with a backslash "\". In this case, just change the single quotes in the command to double quotes. . This information has been misleading me, thank you for your patience and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Perl,

```
$ perl -pe ' s/_.+?\s/ /g' kdong.txt
ENST00000515896.1   0.177145    0.356609
ENST00000425026.1 0.024620    0.049561
ENST00000286448.11  8.465151    17.041147
ENST00000479687.6   0.002051    0.004128
```

Comment: Thank you, for a file I use the sed tool faster, batch processing does need to be added to the script. I will modify this command and add it to the script. This is convenient, thank you again.

Comment: glad that it worked for you.. perl solutions are always portable.. with sed and awk, you need to careful abt GNU or not.. and HP or Debian unix.. etc..

Comment: But the label I chose is linux, emm...So sorry, thank you for your help again.

Comment: that should not be a problem at all.. ok fine